# How to show QGIS maps in android application?

Tags: qgis, android, mysql

I have created map using QGIS software and trying to display data-set records on that map. Also developed android application where user want to see that map.
But I am stuck in how to show this QGIS map on android application.

I am working on crime profiling and showing on map to user phone.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Opensourse JavaScript libraries like leaflet or Openlayers to create a web appilication using the maps created using QGIS with the help of GeoServer and load it into a webview in your android application. If you have only static data then you can use [qgis2leaf](http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/leaflet_maps_with_qgis2leaf.html) plugin in QGIS to create a web map and load it to a webview

Comment: Sir, Showing map is initial task. I have to check user current location on map with crime data and If it is in crime affected zone then have to generate message accordingly. As per your suggestion with webview I can not able to process anything on that like i mention above.

Comment: you can use the GeoJSON created by the qgis2leaf plugin or you can request it from GeoServer for this purpose. Compare user location(lat-long) with the one in the GeoJSON, and generate message accordingly

Answer (score 0):

By far the simplest way is to save the map as a PDF and then view the PDF in Android using any PDF viewer.